# Automatically load kernel module

Tags: linux, opensuse, opensuse-11.3

I'd like openSUSE to automatically load a kernel module (e.g. `libsas`) at boot time even if no device requires it. In Ubuntu, you would add the module name to the file `/etc/modules`. Is this the correct place for openSUSE as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't use openSUSE personally, but I did a little google searching and found this help:

> This file is in a weird place. It's
>   not under /etc/modules.conf; It's
>   under /etc/sysconfig.
>
> cd to /etc/sysconfig
>
> open the 'kernel' file in an editor
>   then add the required module to the
>   MODULES_LOADED_ON_BOOT variable.
>
> eg:
>
> To start the module atl1 at boot time
>   edit it this way:
>
> MODULES_LOADED_ON_BOOT="atl1"

[Source](http://chickenandbeans.vox.com/library/post/loading-modules-on-boot-with-opensuse.html)

Comment: hakuna shida! (mean no problem in Swahili)